# Removing Unique and Reverse pairs using Awk or Perl

Tags: perl, awk

Below is my sample file (column 1 and column 2 separated by a tab)

```
P49418"\t"O43426
P49418"\t"O43426
O43426"\t"P49418
......
```

I need only one representative for the given three pairs shown above.

```
P49418"\t"O43426
```

Similar efforts need to be performed on rest of the file. How it can be performed using `awk` or Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should work:

```
awk -F'\t' '!a[$1,$2]++ && !a[$2,$1]++' file
```

use both fields in both order as key to the array and check for duplicates.

```
$ cat file
P49418  O43426
P49418  O43426
O43426  P49418
$ awk -F'\t' '!a[$1,$2]++ && !a[$2,$1]++' file
P49418  O43426
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a hash table to record items you have seem so far, after finished reading input data, just output the keys of that hash table.

If you want to keep the order of items, you need an extra list to accumulate the results.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %record;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @field = split;
    $record{join "  ", sort { $b cmp $a } @field} = 1;
}

foreach my $r (keys %record) {
    print "$r\n";
}

__DATA__
P49418  O43426
P49418  O43426
O43426  P49418
```